# entityframework core VS2017 migration file and designer file creating separately

Tags: visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core

I am using VS2017 v15.4.1. and using EF Core 2.0.
When i create a migration, the migration script is created inside \Migrations folder but the .designer.cs file is creating separately.

Can anyone help how to make the designer file get created inside the main migration file?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we're all waiting for issue [dotnet/project-system#159](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/159) to get fixed.  Until then, you can manually edit the `*.csproj` file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="MyMigration.Designer.cs">
    <DependentUpon>MyMigration.cs</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```